# Is PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_IP secure enough to $_GET an IP address?

Tags: php, xss, injection

I need to pass an IP to a PHP page, and it would be convenient to be able to use GET, but I know that's sort of asking for trouble, so I want to triple-check that I'm handling it securely.

```
if(!filter_var($_GET["ip"], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    echo "Invalid IP.";
    die();
}

$ip = (string)$_GET["ip"];
```

Is this secure enough to be able to put $ip in a database or display it on a page? Or are there any vulnerabilities with FILTER_VALIDATE_IP (or perhaps the way the code is structured) that I should worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been issues with [`filter_var` when used with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/23359/discuss) in the past, however I cannot find any vulnerabilities with `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`.

Even though an IP address does not contain characters that have special meaning within HTML (e.g. `<`) or have characters that can break out of a database query (e.g. `'`), I would treat the value like any other string value and use parameterised queries to store this within a DB, or HTML encode when displaying to the page.

This would guard against any future changes such as if it is later changed to a host name from user input - the value would still be safe for both operations.